# How do you cure Lover's Pox?

Tags: crusader-kings-3

In crusader kings 3 during a feast I got drunk and ended up in bed with one of my friends wives. This resulted in me contracting a venereal disease. I also ended up passing this along to my own wife, and apparently the STD is inheritable.

As this disease gives an opinion penalty to many of my values I want to get rid of it. Is there a reliable way to cure the STD?

Comment: Please don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Lover's Pox** is normally an incurable disease, that, like all diseases, will be intermittently treated by your Court Physician.

I had my stressed out High King become **Rakish** and acquire **Lover's Pox** in my own game, and **mystic** treatment eventually won out. You do need a *critical success* with the mystic treatment, however.

Do note that your physician's success chance is tied to both their Learning stat and what level of the "Physician" perk they have; exact success chance is random, and not shown to the player, and is also affected by whether or not you decide on "safe", "risky", and (when available) "mystic" treatments. (available via the Wise Man / Wise Woman traits)

So, "Reliable"? Unfortunately not -- but if you're lucky and willing to dabble in alternative medicines, there's hope!

### Further Updates

Based on the comments and my original answer, I went rooting around in the game's "events" files, and, to the best of my understanding, was finally able to confirm that ***Mystic treatment Critical Success can cure Lover's Pox!***

The relevant code is identified as "MYSTIC TREATMENT: CRITICAL SUCCESS" (event: health.3108) in the `Steam/steamapps/common/Crusader Kings III/game/events/health_events.txt` file.

Within this block, the event makes special exception for leprosy (the other "incurable" disease in the game), but notably *does not* prevent a critical success for any other disease -- such as Lover's Pox. Mystery (hopefully) solved!

Comment: Your physician healed Lover's Pox? Then [the wiki](https://ck3.paradoxwikis.com/Traits#Diseases) got to be wrong, because it states Lover's Pox is not curable.

Comment: They did indeed. It's not impossible for the wiki to be wrong, of course, but perhaps the Esoteric Treatment makes a difference? It was cured after my Wise-Woman physician threw a beehive at me.

Comment: Most of the physician treatments sound that implausible from a 21st century perspective. But the placebo effect is strong in them.

Comment: @RavenDreamer You should probably add that your Physician was a Wise Woman/Mystic/Miracle Worker under the bit about success chance, because this may have been the only reason she could cure this "incurable" disease.

Comment: Confirmed that the "Mystic Treatment" is an exception to Lover's pox!